# Jruby on Rails logging with Tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, logging, jruby

I have a jruby/rails (4.1) app that I want to deploy through Tomcat. I made the app log through stdout by adding

```
    config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

in `config/application.rb`, and the log lines are going to `catalina.log`.

We would like the app logs to go to a separate Tomcat logfile. Is it possible? how can it be configured?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not set `config.logger` at all ... it will log to where servlet `log` goes

so simply do not do anything at all with `config.logger` (just leave the default) and it should work (assuming JRuby-Rack of course). otherwise there are 2 options :

- use a Java logging library (in case of TC that is either JUL or Log4J) and [configure](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack#logging) JRuby-Rack to delegate
- or simply `config.logger = Logger.new('logs/rails.log')` in this case make sure you set a formatter to include timestamps

**NOTE:** be aware that in the first case the Java logging library will receive all logs from Rails at the info level (loggers are not mapped "1-to-1") ... this might change in a future JRuby-Rack 1.2 release.

Comment: Sorry if the answer to the following question is obvious (I dont have experience with tomcat): can I set the logfile/rotation policy for a deployed app in the tomcat config? or each app running inside tomcat has to take care of their own log files?

Comment: well yes you can ... you would need to use the first case and configure tomcat's logging sub-system (I do think the default is per day rotation for every deployed apps - try and see).

Comment: Ok.. I opted for the simpler second option, to stop logging to stdout and began logging to a directory in /var/log. In `application.rb`: `config.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join("/var/log/myapp",Rails.env + ".log"),5,5*1024*1024)` `